# returnMap[date]++; error : The method '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter

Hello I try to make null safety migration, but I have an error with   `++` from     `returnMap[date]++;` . I don't know how to write correctly in null stafety. Thank you

Here is my code

thank you

```
 for (var i = x; i < list_conso.length; i++) {
          DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.parse(list_conso[i]);
          String date = "${parsedDate.year}-${parsedDate.month}-${parsedDate.day}";
          date = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(parsedDate);


          if (returnMap.containsKey(date)) {
            returnMap[date]++;  //The method '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

          } else {
            returnMap[date] = 1;

          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have checked that `returnMap` contains `date`, you can use:

```
returnMap[date]!++;
```

The exclamation mark tells the compiler you are sure that `returnMap[date]` exists and is not `null`.

Comment: Hello, I try but I have this error : Illegal assignement to non-assignable expression

Comment: Can you try `returnMap[date] = returnMap[date]! + 1;` ?